# Laravel 4: Relation executing query using the wrong row

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

I have a relation I'm trying to get working that seems to be searching by the wrong column. I have a model, userwords, that should be getting an associated word with it. I want it to be using the word_id column from the userword table to search for a word by the id in the word table, but instead it seems to be using the id of the userword row to search for the word. I thought that perhaps that if I told it which column to use in the third parameter of hasOne() it would work, but to no avail. The code in question is:

```
public function word(){
    return $this->hasOne('Word', 'id', 'word_id');
}
```

any help or ideas would be appreciated! Also if you need more information, please just let me know and i'll update this here! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your parent table is `userword` and related child table is `word`, in this case, `Userword` model should contain following method for making the relation with `word` table:

```
class Userwords {

    protected $table = 'userword';

    public function word(){
        return $this->hasOne('Word', 'userword_id'); // use the foreign key here
    }

}
```

In this case, your `word` table should contain the `userword_id` as a foreign key. So, if you have a different foreign key defined word table then use that foreign key in the place of `userword_id`.

Also remember that, tables should use plural name of the word, for example, `words` should be the table name but you used `word` and the `Model` should use a singular name, for example, `Word` for the `words` table, so you have a different name convension here so use the `protected $table = 'word'` in your `Word` model and in `Userwords` model use `protected $table = 'userword'`. So, finally, it should be something like this:

```
class Userword {

    // change the table name in database (use userwords)
    protected $table = 'userwords';

    public function word(){
        return $this->hasOne('Word', 'userword_id'); // use the foreign key here
    }

}
```

For `words` table, it should be:

```
class Word {

    // change the table name in database (use words)
    protected $table = 'words';

    public function userwords(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Userword');
    }

}
```

Read the manual for more information about [Laravel Model Relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships).